# Promise validation using nestJs && class-validator

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I'm working on a DTO(data transfer object) where I put directly validations based on what `class validator` provides

here is a sample:

```
import { IsDefined, IsNotEmpty, Min, ValidatePromise } from 'class-validator';

export class UpdateMentorParamDto {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Min(1, {
    message: 'the Id in the params is supposed to be a valid id number greater than 0',
  })
  @ValidatePromise()
  id: number;

}
```

This is how I'm using it in the controller

```
import { UpdateMentorParamDto } from './dtos/update-mentor-param.dto';
import { Controller, Put, Param, UsePipes, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('/users')
export class UsersController {
  @Put('/:id')
  @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  updateMentor(@Param() params: UpdateMentorParamDto) {
    // some code
  }
}
```

I saw [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-promises) that it is possible to do Promise validation with class-validator.

this is how they suggest we do it:

```
import {ValidatePromise, Min} from "class-validator";

export class Post {

    @Min(0)
    @ValidatePromise()
    userId: Promise<number>;
}
```

My question is this:

Before I proceed with the update, I need to make sure that the record whose Id is provided in the params actually exists in the database. I assume it is possible to do that with the Promise validation approach suggested on the readme of class-validator.

If that is really possible, how do I do that with the structure that I've shown above?